# Convertir int a float SQL

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de obtener las decimales de una operacion:

```
SELECT CAST(22*100/148 AS FLOAT)
```

Mi resultado es 14 y necesito que sea 14.86 como muestra el resultado una calculadora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te sugiero que hagas el casteo del divisor:

```
SELECT 22*100/CAST(148 AS FLOAT)
```

Sino, los literales de los números son considerados enteros, por lo que la división final será un entero. Otra posibilidad es indicar un literal que no se preste a confusión:

```
SELECT 22*100/148.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `convert` para obtener el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(FLOAT,22*100) / 148)
```

También te dejo un ejemplo con `cast`, es cuestión de usar una sintaxis parecida a tu caso, sin embargo casteamos el entero a `FLOAT` antes de hacer la división:

```
SELECT (CAST(22*100 AS FLOAT) / 148)
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.